# Java SimpleDateFormat Cannot format given Object as a Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert string to date using date format and used the following code but its shows an error.

```
      public static Date ConvertStringtodate(String Date) throws ParseException {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Date Teststart = dateFormat.parse(Date);
            return Teststart;
        }

        public static void main(String[]agrs) throws ParseException {
            System.out.println(ConvertStringtodate("2022.02.10 17:54:55"));
        }
```

Here is the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
> format given Object as a Date     at
> java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:310)  at
> java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)

Comment: `hh` in your format pattern should be `HH` - read the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat` closely to see the difference.

Comment: Although it's odd that the exception mentions `format` when you're actually calling `parse` - please could you include the *full* stack trace?

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet
This is what i received in console
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
 at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:310)
 at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
 at pages.CommonFunctionOfpages.ConvertStringtodate(CommonFunctionOfpages.java:317)
 at pages.CommonFunctionOfpages.main(CommonFunctionOfpages.java:322)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't produce that stack trace - it would produce a stack trace calling `java.text.DateFormat.parse`. (I've just tried your exact code.) In future, please make the code you provide reflect the error you provide. As well as the answer you've received, I'd strongly advise: a) start following Java naming conventions; b) use java.time instead of the old java.util.Date and java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the main method, you are sending date as "2022.02.10 17:54:55". However, you wrote format of the pattern as "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss". Change the pattern at the SimpleDateFormat constructor as "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss".

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the slashes '/' in the date input. for some reason the. The input string was "01/01/1991" instead of "01-01-1991". So I just replaced the slashes with dashes and everything worked just fine.

```
private Date convertStringToDate(String payload) throws ParseException {
        payload = payload.replace("/", "-");
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        java.util.Date utilDate = formatter.parse(payload);
        return new Date(utilDate.getTime());
    }
```